ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.embeddings'
I am using python 3.7.16 in a virtual environment (venv). Upon running the code below I get into an error regarding the langchain.embeddings module. I cannot upgrade langchain higher than 0.0.27, since it is not compatible with python versions < 3.8. Is setting up Neo4j database impossible while staying at my current version of python?
Code:
from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPGStore

graph_store = Neo4jPGStore(
  username=os.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"),
  password=os.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD"),
  url=os.getenv("NEO4J_URI"),
  refresh_schema=False
)

Error log:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35120/1908928590.py in <module>
----> 1 from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPGStore
      2 
      3 
      4 graph_store = Neo4jPGStore(
      5   username=os.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"),

~/Documents/git_stuff/LeuphanaStuff/MasterThesis/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llama_index/__init__.py in <module>
     12 
     13 # embeddings
---> 14 from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
     15 from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
     16 

~/Documents/git_stuff/LeuphanaStuff/MasterThesis/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/langchain.py in <module>
      4 from typing import Any, List
      5 
----> 6 from langchain.embeddings.base import Embeddings as LCEmbeddings
      7 
      8 from llama_index.embeddings.base import BaseEmbedding

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.embeddings'


Try downgrading llama-index to a version compatible with langchain 0.0.27

@cottontail The lowest version of llama-index didn't help either.
